# How to add totals row to excel power query?

Tags: excel, grouping, powerquery, subtotal

I have produced a table like the one below by using 'group' function in excel power query

```
score 1 score 2 score 3
A   6   25  50
B   8   30  20
C   15  15  30
D   20  0   10
```

I want to add a totals row (equivalent to "show totals for column" in a normal pivot table), so result would be like this

```
score 1 score 2 score 3
A   6   25  50
B   8   30  20
C   15  15  30
D   20  0   10
Total 49    70      110
```

Anyone knows if there is a simple way to do this? Thank you, RY

Comment: Why do you want to add it in PQ?

Comment: I am using the query output table as MI slide and want to show totals without having to add another step / separate query

Comment: Why can't you just add a totals row to the table?

Comment: @Rory - do you mean adding totals row to the output of the query i.e. outside of the query editor? Wouldn't that row get overwritten by the query output any time the number of rows changes? Unless, I did this above the query output - hmm.. this could work

Comment: If you output as a Table, it has a built-in option to have a totals row, which will adjust with the table.

Comment: could you point me where I can find this option? I cannot see it in the menu. Thanks

Comment: Should be on the Table tab, IIRC. (on a Mac at the moment)

Comment: It will, however, reset the total row's contents to the default on every refresh. This means that the last colum in that row will contain the column's sum, and all others will be empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {}, {{"letter", each "Total"},
                                     {"score 1", each List.Sum([score 1])},
                                     {"score 2", each List.Sum([score 2])}, 
                                     {"score 3", each List.Sum([score 3])}}),
    append = Table.Combine({Source, group})
in
    append
```

Or:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    cols = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    group = Table.Group(Source, {}, List.Zip({cols, {each "Total"}&
                                    List.Transform(List.Skip(cols), 
                                    (x)=>each List.Sum(Table.Column(_,x)))})),
    append = Table.Combine({Source, group})
in
    append
```

Or:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {}, List.TransformMany(Table.ColumnNames(Source),
                                    (x)=>{each if x = "letter" then "Total" 
                                    else List.Sum(Table.Column(_,x))}, (x,y)=>{x,y})),
    append = Table.Combine({Source, group})
in
    append
```

Comment: Nice - I always forget you can make intermediate steps and then reference back to them. In terms of selecting which apporach to use the OP can choose whether its more important for it to be able to accept new columns being added/names being changed (in which case my soultion is better I think) or to minimse the number of queries and have a more elegent method (and presumably get slightly better performance) with your solution.

Comment: Well, added a couple of options. Unfortunately, your code doesn't work on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would do this in PowerQuery rather than a pivottable but the only way I can think of is to duplicate the table, unpivot the columns and then repivot it using sum as an aggregation. Then you could append the table to your orginal query.

Your code would look something like for the table you want to create the totals in.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Note you may have to choose to aggregate by count but you can change the code to sum (On the #"Pivot Column" line change `List.Count` to `List.Sum`.

You will get an error for the A,B,C,D col - you can replace this with Total if you would like by using the Replace Errors function.

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to add a total row to a Power Query that was loaded to a table. Just skip a row and add a total row. This seems to work for me. Just make sure you lock the first cell in your sum formulas. ex `=SUM($C$2:C25)`

Example 1

[image: 1]

Example 2

[image: 2]