# Bring Value with Sumifs in Pow.Query language to specified row, and column(location)

Tags: powerquery, sumifs

Next step? I have brought with sumifs and a lot sumif from other workbook, information to the exact row, column in excel workbook. Now I want to do the same with query language. I can bring two values if condition is met, but then it is unclear how I will bring the total sum to the one row in excel workbook. Can anyone show me the path? I guess I will need Data Model...

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Sumif", each if [Column2] =2 or [Column2]=1 then [Column3]+[Column4] else 0)


let
    Source = Folder.Files...
    #"C:\Users...
    #"Imported Excel" = Excel.Workbook(#"C:\...
    SegPL_Chart = #"Imported Excel"{[Name="SegPL_Chart"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(SegPL_Chart,12),
    #"Removed Alternate Rows" = Table.AlternateRows(#"Removed Top Rows",1,1,90),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Alternate Rows"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Promoted Headers", each ([Col1]="1" or [Col1]="2")),
    #"Table Group = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {}, List.TransformMany(Table.ColumnNames(#"Filtered Rows",(x)=>{each if x = "Names" then "Totals" else List.Sum(Table.Column(_,x))},(x,y)=>{x,y})),
    #"append" = Table.Combine({#"Filtered Rows",#"Table Group"})
in
    #"append"
```

It gives an error "in" Token comma needed..? What else I need to do bring total rows?

Comment: you may want to post a data sample and explain the desired result. Right now there is confusion about what you want to achieve. Edit your question and add 5 - 10 rows of data, then explain in words what the desired outcome is and what processing logic leads to that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several steps to create several helper columns with intermediate results of conditional sums. Then you can create a new column, sum up all the intermediate results and the delete the helper columns with the intermediate results.

Keep in mind that unlike Excel, the calculations in Power Query always return constants and you can then delete calculated columns you no longer need. So,

- Create helper column 1 with complicated IF and Sum scenario
- Create helper column 2 with complicated IF and Sum scenario
- Create total column to add column 1 + column 2
- Delete helper columns and keep only the total column

Comment: could you go more and give some exact codes how to write them? I would be grateful if there is possibility

Comment: You already have the code for creating one column in your question. Just use that same approach to create other helper columns. Then create a new column and use logic to add together the helper columns into one total. Maybe you need another condition here, maybe not. I don't know your data.

Comment: Ok, I will try to go by way you said. It will not be hard to find DeletColumn, AddTotal I think. Let' see

Comment: So, as I understood, We are working through Columns in PowerQuery not with Rows. I mean I have to add TotalCOlumn, Then delete empty Totals, I cannot add at the end new totalSum row?

Comment: @user16316847 See [How to Add Totals Row to Excel Power Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868585/how-to-add-totals-row-to-excel-power-query)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the way I read it, the OP wants to do a conditional sum of several values in the same row, not a totals row.

Comment: I read it differently because he wrote in comments *"I cannot add at the end new totalSum row?"*  And in his question *"how I will bring the total sum to the one row in excel workbook"*  And also I had previously supplied him with a formula for a conditional sum on a row by row basis.

Comment: Dear @teylyn and Ron Rosenfeld, I am new in query language, but I see you are also having difficulties to understand exactly what I want. I think, for tomorrow I will be able to solve my problem and let you know...the story of it comes, I did the same calculation with vba macro, I sum the number of cells with condition, then bring exact value to one cell where it has name e.g total sum of assets...As I understand from the resource you gave me Ron, in query I need first to sum horizontally then doing sth in vertically bring the value...I am also in confusion, but I think I will solve it

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I did as it is written on the page you shared a link. I changed [Source] to the last line of my code, where I have applied filters, etc...It gave me error on "in" showing comma is needed? I am lost...What is next I do not know, I tried to change code( like group to #"Table Group", append to #"Append maybe syntax is different in my PowerQuery version. But he error is there...Can you lead please which direction to go for solving this issue

Comment: @user16316847 Impossible for me to tell where your problem is from what you have posted.  But the solution is to create a separate, one-row table with the Totals for the columns you are interested in; then append that table with your original table. If the column you want to sum is named `Conditional Sum`, then something like `totals = Table.FromRecords({[Conditional Sum=List.Sum(#"Added Custom"[Conditional Sum])]},{"Conditional Sum"})` creates the new table.  Then `Combine` the two tables, naming the columns you want to show in your final result.

Comment: Guys, I think I am able to finish it. At least I came very near...By Filtering, Transposing and Reverse Transposing the data, the on Pivot Table adding Measure...If you want I can share code. But I will need shortcut path, for not duplicating every row...I think would be better if I will ask it as a question in new thread...?

Comment: Shame that despite us asking, you never posted a data sample, so we could see what the problem was. If you don't respond to these requests, it is really hard to help and your chances of getting help next time will dwindle.

Comment: @teylyn, It is a work file, confidential I am sorry but I cannot post it.

Answer (score 0):

That gives me exact result what I was looking for, but it is with DAX formula in PowerPivot:

`=SUMX(FILTER('TableName',[ColName] = 1),'TableName'[ColName2])`

So would be glad to convert it to Power-Query formula